# How to specify where the Lambda function should look for dependencies in S3 using Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I would like to use Boto3 to upload a script to S3,create a Lambda function specifying the S3 key to run the script. To speed up the process, I would also have some Python Dependencies pre-stored in S3,how could I specify where the lambda function should look for those dependencies? Also, how can I delete the script from S3 once the function is executed, using Boto3?

My code will be similar as follows:

```
import zipfile
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('function.zip', 'w')
zip.write('index.js', 'path/on/disk/index.js')
.......

client.put_object(Body=archive, Bucket='bucket-name', Key='function.zip')

lambda_Client = boto3.client('lambda', aws_access_key_id=accessKey,
                       aws_secret_access_key=secretKey,region_name=region)
response = lambda_Client.create_function(
            Code={
                'S3Bucket': 'bucket-name',
                'S3Key': 'function.zip', #how can i create or fetch this S3Key
            },
            Description='Process image objects from Amazon S3.',
            FunctionName='function_name',
            Handler='index.handler',
            Publish=True,
            Role='arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/lambda-role',
            Runtime='nodejs12.x',
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that by "dependencies", you mean third-party Python packages.

Lambda will not fetch dependencies for your Python Lambda function. You need to [package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html) the dependencies when you initially [create](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_function) the Lambda function or when you subsequently [update](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.update_function_code) the Lambda function.

To delete a Lambda function, use [delete_function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.delete_function). To delete a script, or other, from S3, use [delete_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_object).

If by "dependencies", you simply mean assets that you have stored in S3, such as JSON files or other, then use the S3 features of boto3 such as [get_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) to retrieve them.